# How can I force center specific element in flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center specific `div` inside `flex` container. You will understand me better with the code:

Here is my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        div.flex_container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: baseline;
            align-content: stretch;
        }

        div.red_box {
            background-color: red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        div.blue_box {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        div.yellow_box {
            background-color: yellow;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex_container">
        <div class="red_box"></div>
        <div class="blue_box"></div>
        <div class="yellow_box"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

*Alternatively here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ts5ayLph/6/) code.*

Currently, **Blue Box is in the center** location, but **I want a Red Box in the center** and others on the right of it.

How can achieve this, how can I force center specific element inside `flex` container?

**EDIT: Without changing order.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I'm not wrong, what you're asking is to change the order of the coloured boxes? If that's the case then you are half way through your goal. Your code is correct. All you have to do is to specify the `order: <order_number>` in the elements and you will achieve your desire result. Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mrwp5nxL/

Comment: @rand0m I'm sorry if you misunderstood. I edited question. _(Added: Without changing order.)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `justify-content: center` and add `margin-left` to `red_box`

```css
div.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: stretch;
}

div.red_box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  /*                       ↓ width / 2) */
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

div.blue_box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
}

div.yellow_box {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex_container'>
  <div class='red_box'></div>
  <div class='blue_box'></div>
  <div class='yellow_box'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! It solved my problem, but can't we do it without `margin`? Thanks anyway!

Comment: This impossible with flex features. We can use `margin-left` or `left` or `display:grid`

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **CSS order property**.

Just by adding `order: number;` to your boxes properties. Like this:

```css
div.flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  align-content: stretch;
}

div.red_box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  order: 2;
}

div.blue_box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  order: 1;
}

div.yellow_box {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex_container'>
  <div class='red_box'></div>
  <div class='blue_box'></div>
  <div class='yellow_box'></div>
</div>
```

Check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) for more details about Ordering Flex Items